# Running API/gem on heroku gives Load error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, mollie

I use the payment provider Mollie in my Ruby on Rails app. It works locally but not on heroku. When I call the API, it gives the error: 500: Load error: cannot load such file -- Mollie/Api/Client. Does someone know how to load the API on heroku? Update: I think that it has something to do with the location where heroku saves the gems. And that it can't find the location of the gem (??)

I installed the gem locally by running

```
$ gem install mollie-api-ruby
```

I also added the gem to my gemfile (but don't know if this is necessary).

```
gem 'mollie-api-ruby'
```

I am not experienced in Ruby on Rails and Heroku, but I hope that someone has a tip to get this working. Thanks!

---

I request this API in a controller by:

```
def create

    @thrill = Thrill.find(params[:thrill_id])
    if @thrill.reservations.length < @thrill.training.tr_max_attendants
        @reservation = current_user.reservations.create(reservation_params)

        if @reservation

            require 'Mollie/API/Client'

            mollie = Mollie::API::Client.new('test_gUejkz43UkdeCauC22J6UNq')

            payment = mollie.payments.create(
                amount: @reservation.thrill.training.tr_price,
                description: @reservation.thrill.training.tr_name,
                redirect_Url: 'http://8a3a73cb.ngrok.io/your_trips',
                webhookUrl: 'http://8a3a73cb.ngrok.io/notify',
                metadata: {
                    reservationid: @reservation.id
                }
            )

            @reservation.update_attributes payid:payment.id
            redirect_to payment.payment_url

        else
            redirect_to @thrill.training, notice: "Helaas, de training is vol"
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: you definitely need to add the gem to Gemfile. Also run `bundle` locally, make a new commit, and push that to heroku. You can also use `heroku run rails console` to inspect your app environment

Comment: Thanks for your message. Both locally and on heroku bundle install states that the app is 'using mollie-api-ruby 2.0.1', so that seems right to me. Is it maybe the way I use 'require 'Mollie/API/Client'?

Comment: Ok, found the answer. It had to be lowercase : require 'mollie/api/client'

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the answer. It had to be lowercase : require 'mollie/api/client'